# How to display date from table to jdatechooser

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to run the following code but it showing errors but in youtube the same code is written and working fine.

```
String date=rs.getString("DOB");      
((JTextField)date_chooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(date);﻿
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHeGI.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace of the exception that your are getting?

Comment: sorry..what is stacktrace..?

Comment: if u r talking about the exception message then the image is being uploaded..

Comment: the image name is "Error"

Comment: If you read that message, it says that the application has encountered `java.lang.RunTimeException`. I was asking about that exception stacktrace.

Comment: Sir can u please tell me how to use this with an application..actually i am new in java world..